# Why doesn't line 4 generate an unchecked exception?

Tags: java

```
/*1.*/ List l = new ArrayList<Number>();
/*2.*/ List<String> ls = l;       // unchecked warning
/*3.*/ l.add(0, new Integer(42)); // another unchecked warning
/*4.*/ String s = ls.get(0);
```

If the lines 2 and 3 produce an unchecked warning then why doesn't the 4th line generate a unchecked warning since compiler does not know what 'ls' is referring to (`List<String>` or `List<Integer>`).

(Note: edited from the OP's original post to make the code display as presumably intended - notably include the type parameters for `List<E>` everywhere.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler *thinks* that `ls` will genuinely refer to a list of strings - line 4 would be "safe" (in terms of type safety) if there hadn't already been dangerous operations - namely line 2.

With no other warnings involved, a `List<String>` should always end referring to a list which only contains references to strings (or null). But if you've already broken type safety, all bets are off (other than that the VM will catch those type violations at execution time).

The warning shows which lines are dangerous - in this case, places where you're using a raw type, i.e. you're saying, "Well, we've got a list here. I've no idea what's in it though."

Line 4 doesn't refer to any variables of raw types - it *only* refers to calling `get` on a `List<String>`, and assigning the return value to a `String` variable. If you think this should produce a warning, please show which section of the Java Language Specification suggests that a warning is appropriate - I think you'll find it hard to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Line 4 produces no compile-time warning because the type of `ls` is `List<String>` which means its `get` methods returns a `String` or `null`.  Any violation will be caught at compile time and will result in a `ClassCastException`.

EDIT:

There are a number of things that the compiler knows about that the bytecode verifier and interpreter do not.

1. generic types
2. compile-time-only annotations
3. checked exceptions
4. outer-class privates

The java compiler knows about these things and so points out errors in their use, but the bytecode verifier and interpreter do not so it "erases" them when producing the portion of the `.class` file meant for the interpreter.

So the steps in compilation are

1. Look for all the classes needed by looking for `.java` and `.class` files.
2. Make sure everything type checks.
3. Erase information not needed by the interpreter (but hide it awway in case javac gets called with the `.class` on its input CLASSPATH).
4. Produce the output `.class` files.

Comment: But the List<String> will be made List during type erasure.But how does the compiler know?

Comment: But the List<String> will be made List during type erasure.But how does the compiler know?

Comment: Because type erasure happens during compilation, i.e. the compiler checks the signatures before erasing.

Comment: @Rekha, meriton is right.  Please see my edit which explains how erasure fits into the compilation flow.

Answer (score 1):

Line 4 doesn't give a warning because `ls` is declared as a `List<String>`, the `ls.get(0)` returns a String (as far as the compiler knows), and you're assigning it to a String variable `s`

To the compiler, everything looks correct - it does not look at the fact that you "illegally" pointed it at a `List<Integer>`.

You will, however, get a ClassCastException are *runtime*.

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 is absolutely fine. You are probably thinking your code is :

```
String s = l.get(0);   // this will not compile without the cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 does not warrant an unchecked warning, as it does not introduce the potential of type errors. The declaration of `ls` says it's a `List<String>`, and `List<String>` contain `String`s. That it does not is a pathological situation called [heap pollution](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#111088) that can arise only if unchecked warnings are incorrectly suppressed, but that's not the fault of line 4.

Line 4 does, however, throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, as the compiler is aware of the possiblity of *heap pollution*, and emits an additional cast to verify that the returned object is of the proper type before invoking methods on it.